# How i can calculate distance between three or four latitude-longitude points? (Haversine formula)

Tags: c#

I have haversine formula for two points and its works great. But how i can find distance between three or more lat/lon points?

Example haversine formula for two points:

```
// C# program for the haversine formula 
using System; 
class GFG 
{ 

static double haversine(double lat1, double lon1, 
                        double lat2, double lon2) 
{ 
    // distance between latitudes and longitudes 
    double dLat = (Math.PI / 180) * (lat2 - lat1); 
    double dLon = (Math.PI / 180) * (lon2 - lon1); 

    // convert to radians 
    lat1 = (Math.PI / 180) * (lat1); 
    lat2 = (Math.PI / 180) * (lat2); 

    // apply formulae 
    double a = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dLat / 2), 2) +  
               Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dLon / 2), 2) *  
               Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2); 
    double rad = 6371; 
    double c = 2 * Math.Asin(Math.Sqrt(a)); 
    return rad * c; 
} 

// Driver Code 
public static void Main() 
{ 
    double lat1 = 51.5007; 
    double lon1 = 0.1246; 
    double lat2 = 40.6892; 
    double lon2 = 74.0445; 
    Console.WriteLine(haversine(lat1, lon1,  
                                lat2, lon2) + " K.M."); 
} 
}
```

Comment: See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance

Answer (score 0):

Build a graph where each point is a node and distance between two points(nodes) is the weight of the edge between these two nodes. Then run the [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) from the starting point, you will find the distance (shortest paths) between all points from the starting point.